# Copy jQuery object to modal, then hide or show, then display

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I want to display a footer within a modal only when user is logged in (via ajax).

I want the footer itself to be contained in the main HTML page, which can be over-ridden by other users.

So I have a hidden container holding it on the main page:

```
<div style="display:none" id="signupModalFooterContainer">
    <div class="modal__footer btn-group" class="signupModalFooter">
        You are logged in
    </div>
</div>
```

I can add it to the popup content:

```
popUpContent += $('#signupModalFooterContainer').html();
```

How can I make the browser re-draw the modal content between running `$('.signupModalFooter').show()` or `$('.signupModalFooter').hide()` after adding it to the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing, recommended by a mentor, is to

- create a "state object" which tracks the "logged in" state as well as holding various other attributes.
- create two render() functions, one to render the modal main content and one to render the inner content, when events are showing feedback within the modal.

The state object looks like this:

```
var my_state = {

    logged_in: (wordpress_i18n_key.loggedIn == 1) ? true : false,
    message: undefined,
    inner_container: '<div id="innerDiv"></div>',
    other_attribute: undefined,

    // Grab the login form from a hidden container in the DOM
    login_form: $('#LogInContainer').html(),

    initialize: function(target){
            this.target = $(target).attr("href");
            this.siteID = $(target).attr('data-someData');
    }

}
```

Where `wordpress_i18n_key.loggedIn` is either a 0 or 1 that wordpress prints out to the HTML page in a `<script></script>` tag to make php variables available to javascript.

This function renders the main modal content:

```
function render_modal(){
    var message = (my_state.message ? '<p>'+my_state.message+'</p>' : '');
    my_state.wrapper = '<div class="modal__wrapper" id="wrapperDiv">';
    if (my_state.logged_in){
        my_state.wrapper += my_state.header;
        my_state.wrapper += '<div class="modal__content" id="contentDiv">'+message+my_state.signup_button+'</div>';
        my_state.wrapper += my_state.footer;
    } else {
        my_state.wrapper += my_state.header;
        my_state.wrapper += '<div class="modal__content" id="contentDiv">'+message+my_state.login_form+'</div>';
    }
    my_state.wrapper += '</div>';
    if ($('#cboxLoadedContent')) {
        $('#cboxLoadedContent').html(my_state.wrapper);
    }
    my_state.message = undefined;
}
```

Where `#cboxLoadedContent` is the main container in the colorbox.js modal.

Then for activity that should show feedback within *part* of the modal:

```
function render_inner_modal_activity(){
    my_state.content = '';
    $('#innerDiv').html = '';
    if (my_state.action == 'processing'){
        my_state.content += my_state.spinner;
    } else if (my_state.action == 'login_failed') {
        my_state.content += my_state.message;
        my_state.content += my_state.login_form;
    } else {
        // login, sign_up_form, etc
        my_state.content += my_state.message;
    }
    if ($('#innerDiv')) {
        $('#innerDiv').html(my_state.content);
    }
}
```

When user clicks modal page button:

```
/**
 * Initial Modal Window to Register for a Class
 *
 * Also leads to options to login and sign-up with API
 *
 */
$(document).on('click', "a[data-target=someButton]", function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    my_state.initialize(this);
    render_mbo_modal();
    $("#modalContainer").load(my_state.target, function () {
        $.colorbox({html: my_state.wrapper,  href: my_state.target});
        $("#modalContainer").colorbox();
    });

});
```

Filling out the modal form, feedback stays in the modal:

```
/**
 * Sign In to API
 */
$(document).on('submit', 'form[id="login"]', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serializeArray();
    var result = { };
    $.each($('form').serializeArray(), function() {
        result[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: mz_mindbody_schedule.ajaxurl,
        type: form.attr('method'),
        context: this, // So we have access to form data within ajax results
        data: {
                action: 'client_log_in',
                form: form.serialize()
            },
        beforeSend: function() {
            my_state.action = 'processing';
            render_mbo_modal_activity();
        },
        success: function(json) {
            var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var result = { };
            $.each($('form').serializeArray(), function() {
                result[this.name] = this.value;
            });
            if (json.type == "success") {
                my_state.logged_in = true;
                my_state.action = 'login';
                my_state.message = json.message;
                render_mbo_modal();
            } else {
                my_state.action = 'login_failed';
                my_state.message = json.message;
                render_mbo_modal_activity();
            }
        } // ./ Ajax Success
    }) // End Ajax
        .fail(function (json) {
            my_state.message = 'ERROR SIGNING IN';
            render_mbo_modal_activity();
            console.log(json);
        }); // End Fail

});
```

And this is the outer container the modal initially references:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalContainer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mzSmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Empty and Replace your html content before showing

```
if (loggedin == 'yes') {
    $('.signupModalFooter').html('You are logged in');
} else {
    $('.signupModalFooter').html('');
}
$('.signupModalFooter').show();
```

Comment: That's not doing the trick, man. Maybe my question wasn't clear. I think you pointed me in the right direction, though. I think that rather than trying to modify the modal content based on user activity, I will instead create a simple state object http://robdodson.me/take-control-of-your-app-with-the-javascript-state-patten and re-render the modal content whenever the user does something. This is getting messy. Will report back.

Comment: Posted the approach what I am going with, below.